# Unix domain sockets ancillary data

Tags: linux, process, ipc

For a multiple process implementation program on linux using fork(), socketpair() is used for  communication between the parent and the child processes.

What is the use of sending ancillary data between processes in the scenario above? socketpair() already provides a two-way communication between the parent and the child. Is it to share file descriptors between the 2 child processes?

To clarify,

1. Why is ancillary data passing necessary when we can always pass back and forth payload using socketpair() connected sockets? What would be a use-case scenario?
2. We can create pipe() or socketpair() in the parent and then fork to create child processes. Then the parent and child can communicate over the created file descriptors. Would ancillary data (over unix sockets) help with communication between two *child* processes?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, without understanding the design of the software you're inspecting.
`socketpair()` is an easy way to create two socket's connecting, and passing each descriptor to the other process, this way you skip the bind(), accept(), connect() code.

Answer (score 0):

Socketpairs are a great way to communicate messages (datagrams) or stream data between parent and child. But they are by no means the only means of inter-process communication (IPC). Other examples of IPC mechanisms for processes on the same host are: shared memory, signals, lock files, or even internet sockets. The particular application requirements and the nature of the communication (i.e. how much back and forth needs to happen) would dictate which of the methods is most appropriate.

You would use the socketpair to exchange datagrams or stream data between your two processes. Ancillary data functions allow you to send other fun things that you couldn't communicate otherwise, such as file descriptors. Unix processes either inherit file descriptors at the time they are created, or they pass them around at any time using ancillary data (see `man cmsg` and `man sendmsg`).

**Communication examples:**

Another useful feature of ancillary data is to authenticate the remote end of a connection ([ex: passing credentials](http://www.oocities.org/margineantm/syspp/background/ancillary.html)) -- the OS can tell you, via ancillary data, which user is peered on the other end of a message or connection. (Admittedly the latter is less useful when both parent and child are running as the same effective user at their respective end of a socketpair).

Ancillary data allows processes to exchange things that didn't yet exist at the time fork() was called. For instance, a child worker process could create a new temporary file a few minutes after the fork(), and pass a file descriptor for it back to the parent using one end of the socketpair it received at birth. Then the parent could pass this file descriptor down again to a different child process.

It's also common for the parent to have more permissions than the child, and so elevated privileges in the parent could allow `open()` to succeed on a protected file, run some authorization algorithm that is not based on Unix permissions, and pass the descriptor down to a child worker.

To pass ancillary data, you need to have some way to communicate beforehand. And by "some way", I mean anything you could call `sendmsg()` on.

[Example: Passing file descriptors over Unix sockets](http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/~ivana/courses/tos/sistemi_knjige/pomocno/apue/APUE/0201433079/ch17lev1sec4.html)